# Substrate AUTHORIZATION pallet runtime issue

Tags: rust, versioning

I am having a versioning issue with the AUTHORIZATION pallet.
I pushed all my changes in the authorization_issue branch: https://github.com/herou/ferrum-x-network-elio/tree/authorization_issue

I am following this documentation: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/authorize-specific-nodes/

I am stuck at this step which can be found in the documentation:  “6.

Check that the configuration can compile by running the following command:”

Logs error:

```
elioprifti@pc-193-62 ferrum-x-network-elio % cargo build --release
   Compiling ferrum-x-runtime v0.0.1 (/Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `ferrum-x-runtime v0.0.1 (/Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/target/release/build/ferrum-x-runtime-14cf937d724cf97a/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/target/release/wbuild/ferrum-x-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.65.0-nightly (2e35f954a 2022-09-01)


  --- stderr
  warning: unused import: `sp_std::str`
    --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/pallets/quamtum-portal/src/lib.rs:59:7
     |
  59 |         use sp_std::str;
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

  warning: crate-level attribute should be in the root module
   --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/pallets/quamtum-portal/src/chain_queries.rs:1:35
    |
  1 | #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
    |                                   ^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unused_attributes)]` on by default

  warning: crate-level attribute should be in the root module
   --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/pallets/quamtum-portal/src/erc_20_client.rs:1:35
    |
  1 | #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
    |                                   ^^^^^^

  warning: crate-level attribute should be in the root module
   --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/pallets/quamtum-portal/src/quantum_portal_client.rs:1:35
    |
  1 | #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
    |                                   ^^^^^^

  warning: `pallet-quantum-portal` (lib) generated 4 warnings
     Compiling ferrum-x-runtime v0.0.1 (/Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime)
  error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/target/release/wbuild/ferrum-x-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-0eeab11c114f6fcf.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/target/release/wbuild/ferrum-x-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-68be5c5d1b108e5b.rmeta

  error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `oom`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/target/release/wbuild/ferrum-x-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-0eeab11c114f6fcf.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/target/release/wbuild/ferrum-x-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-68be5c5d1b108e5b.rmeta

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:339:6
      |
  339 | impl pallet_node_authorization::Config for Runtime {
      |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
  note: required by a bound in `pallet_node_authorization::Config`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/616d33e/frame/node-authorization/src/lib.rs:65:20
      |
  65  |     pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
      |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_node_authorization::Config`

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied in `Call`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:408:3
      |
  408 |         Call: From<LocalCall>,
      |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ within `Call`, the trait `Callable<Runtime>` is not implemented for `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `Callable<T>`:
                frame_system::Pallet<T>
                pallet_aura::Pallet<T>
                pallet_authorship::pallet::Pallet<T>
                pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>
                pallet_base_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_dynamic_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_ethereum::Pallet<T>
                pallet_evm::Pallet<T>
              and 7 others
  note: required because it appears within the type `Call`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^
      = help: see issue #48214
      = help: add `#![feature(trivial_bounds)]` to the crate attributes to enable
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied in `Call`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:448:3
      |
  448 |         Call: From<C>,
      |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ within `Call`, the trait `Callable<Runtime>` is not implemented for `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `Callable<T>`:
                frame_system::Pallet<T>
                pallet_aura::Pallet<T>
                pallet_authorship::pallet::Pallet<T>
                pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>
                pallet_base_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_dynamic_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_ethereum::Pallet<T>
                pallet_evm::Pallet<T>
              and 7 others
  note: required because it appears within the type `Call`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^
      = help: see issue #48214
      = help: add `#![feature(trivial_bounds)]` to the crate attributes to enable
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`, the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: required because it appears within the type `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`
      = note: no field of an enum variant may have a dynamically sized type
      = help: change the field's type to have a statically known size
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
  help: borrowed types always have a statically known size
      |
  455 | &construct_runtime!(
      | +
  help: the `Box` type always has a statically known size and allocates its contents in the heap
      |
  455 ~ Box<construct_runtime!(
  456 |     pub enum Runtime where
    ...
  475 |     }
  476 ~ )>;
      |

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `Event`, the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
  note: required because it appears within the type `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^
  note: required by a bound in `core::clone::Clone`
      = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Clone` which comes from the expansion of the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `Event`, the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
  note: required because it appears within the type `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^
  note: required by a bound in `EncodeLike`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parity-scale-codec-3.1.5/src/encode_like.rs:73:41
      |
  73  | pub trait EncodeLike<T: Encode = Self>: Sized + Encode {}
      |                                         ^^^^^ required by this bound in `EncodeLike`
      = note: this error originates in the derive macro `self::sp_api_hidden_includes_construct_runtime::hidden_include::codec::Encode` which comes from the expansion of the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `Event`, the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
  note: required because it appears within the type `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^
  note: required by a bound in `Decode`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/parity-scale-codec-3.1.5/src/codec.rs:295:19
      |
  295 | pub trait Decode: Sized {
      |                   ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Decode`
      = note: this error originates in the derive macro `self::sp_api_hidden_includes_construct_runtime::hidden_include::codec::Decode` which comes from the expansion of the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `Event`, the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
  note: required because it appears within the type `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^
  note: required by a bound in `From`
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `Event`, the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
  note: required because it appears within the type `Event`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^
  note: required by a bound in `TryInto`
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`, the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: required because it appears within the type `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`
  note: required by a bound in `From`
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`, the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: required because it appears within the type `pallet_node_authorization::Event<Runtime>`
  note: required by a bound in `TryInto`
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ the trait `Callable<Runtime>` is not implemented for `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `Callable<T>`:
                frame_system::Pallet<T>
                pallet_aura::Pallet<T>
                pallet_authorship::pallet::Pallet<T>
                pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>
                pallet_base_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_dynamic_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_ethereum::Pallet<T>
                pallet_evm::Pallet<T>
              and 7 others
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied in `Call`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `Call`, the trait `Callable<Runtime>` is not implemented for `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `Callable<T>`:
                frame_system::Pallet<T>
                pallet_aura::Pallet<T>
                pallet_authorship::pallet::Pallet<T>
                pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>
                pallet_base_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_dynamic_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_ethereum::Pallet<T>
                pallet_evm::Pallet<T>
              and 7 others
  note: required because it appears within the type `Call`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^
  note: required by a bound in `core::clone::Clone`
      = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Clone` which comes from the expansion of the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied in `Call`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/ferrum-x-network-elio/runtime/src/lib.rs:455:1
      |
  455 | / construct_runtime!(
  456 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  457 | |         Block = Block,
  458 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  475 | |     }
  476 | | );
      | |_^ within `Call`, the trait `Callable<Runtime>` is not implemented for `pallet_node_authorization::Pallet<Runtime>`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `Callable<T>`:
                frame_system::Pallet<T>
                pallet_aura::Pallet<T>
                pallet_authorship::pallet::Pallet<T>
                pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>
                pallet_base_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_dynamic_fee::Pallet<T>
                pallet_ethereum::Pallet<T>
                pallet_evm::Pallet<T>
              and 7 others
.............

elioprifti@pc-193-62 ferrum-x-network-elio %
```

Cargo.toml

```
[build-dependencies.substrate-wasm-builder]
branch = 'master'
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '5.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.codec]
default-features = false
features = ['derive']
package = 'parity-scale-codec'
version = '3.1.5'

[dependencies.fp-rpc]
default-features = false
version = "3.0.0-dev"
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git'

[dependencies.pallet-quantum-portal]
default-features = false
version = '1.0.0-dev'
path = '../pallets/quamtum-portal'

[dependencies.fp-self-contained]
default-features = false
version = '1.0.0-dev'
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git'

[dependencies.frame-benchmarking]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
optional = true
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-node-authorization]
branch = "polkadot-v0.9.22"
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.frame-executive]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.frame-support]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.frame-system]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.frame-system-benchmarking]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
optional = true
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.frame-system-rpc-runtime-api]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-aura]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-balances]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-base-fee]
default-features = false
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/"
version = "1.0.0"

[dependencies.pallet-dynamic-fee]
default-features = false
version = "4.0.0-dev"
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git'

[dependencies.pallet-ethereum]
default-features = false
version = '4.0.0-dev'
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git'

[dependencies.pallet-evm]
version = '6.0.0-dev'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git'

[dependencies.pallet-evm-precompile-modexp]
version = "2.0.0-dev"
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git'
default-features = false

[dependencies.pallet-evm-precompile-sha3fips]
version = "2.0.0-dev"
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git'
default-features = false

[dependencies.pallet-evm-precompile-simple]
version = "2.0.0-dev"
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git'
default-features = false

[dependencies.pallet-grandpa]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-randomness-collective-flip]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-sudo]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-timestamp]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-transaction-payment]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.scale-info]
default-features = false
features = ['derive']
version = '2.1.2'

[dependencies.serde]
features = ['derive']
optional = true
version = '1.0.101'

[dependencies.sp-api]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.sp-block-builder]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.sp-consensus-aura]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '0.10.0-dev'

[dependencies.sp-core]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '6.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-inherents]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.sp-io]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '6.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-offchain]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.sp-runtime]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '6.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-session]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.sp-std]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0'

[dependencies.sp-transaction-pool]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.sp-version]
branch = 'master'
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate'
version = '5.0.0'

[dependencies.log]
version = "0.4.14"
default-features = false

[features]
aura = []
default = [
    'std',
    'aura',
]
manual-seal = []
runtime-benchmarks = [
    'frame-benchmarking',
    'frame-system-benchmarking',
    'frame-system/runtime-benchmarks',
    'pallet-ethereum/runtime-benchmarks',
    'pallet-evm/runtime-benchmarks',
]
std = [
    'serde',
    'codec/std',
    'scale-info/std',
    'sp-api/std',
    'sp-block-builder/std',
    'sp-consensus-aura/std',
    'sp-core/std',
    'sp-inherents/std',
    'sp-io/std',
    'sp-offchain/std',
    'sp-runtime/std',
    'sp-session/std',
    'sp-std/std',
    'log/std',
    'sp-transaction-pool/std',
    'sp-version/std',
    'frame-executive/std',
    'frame-support/std',
    'frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std',
    'frame-system/std',
    'pallet-aura/std',
    'pallet-balances/std',
    'pallet-grandpa/std',
    'pallet-randomness-collective-flip/std',
    'pallet-sudo/std',
    'pallet-timestamp/std',
    'pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api/std',
    'pallet-transaction-payment/std',
    'fp-rpc/std',
    'fp-self-contained/std',
    'pallet-base-fee/std',
    'pallet-dynamic-fee/std',
    'pallet-ethereum/std',
    'pallet-evm/std',
    'pallet-evm-precompile-simple/std',
    'pallet-evm-precompile-sha3fips/std',
    'frame-benchmarking/std',
    'pallet-node-authorization/std',
]

[package]
authors = ['Ferrum Network <https://github.com/ferrumnet/ferrum-x-network>']
edition = '2021'
homepage = 'https://ferrum.network'
license = 'Unlicense'
name = 'ferrum-x-runtime'
publish = false
repository = 'https://github.com/ferrumnet/ferrum-x-network'
version = '0.0.1'
[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ['x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu']
```

runtime/lib.rs

```
parameter_types! {
    // Add parameter const for node-authorization pallet
    pub const MaxWellKnownNodes: u32 = 10;
    pub const MaxPeerIdLength: u32 = 128;
}

/// Configure the pallet-node-authorization
impl pallet_node_authorization::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type MaxWellKnownNodes = MaxWellKnownNodes;
    type MaxPeerIdLength = MaxPeerIdLength;
    type AddOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type RemoveOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type ResetOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type SwapOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

Comment: The link is invalid.

Comment: I see. Which part of the code are you interested in so I can post it here?

Comment: I want to see how you build the pallet. Maybe there is something wrong with the macro or `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: I posted the Cargo.toml above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the system part in the runtime/lib.rs.

```rs
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime { .. }
```

---

After some discussion. The problem is that you are trying to use different versions.

`pallet-node-authorization` is on `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.22"` and others dependencies is on `branch = "master"`. You can't do this.

All the dependencies must stay at the same version.

Comment: It is there. I have not forgotten it but I could not post it - so many characters

Comment: Do you have time for a short call? If yes, where can I find you?